# convert string rep of hexadecimal into actual hexadecimal

Tags: python, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to parse hex or decimal int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604240/how-to-parse-hex-or-decimal-int-in-python)

i have a bunch of Hexadecimal colors in a database stored as strings.

e.g. '0xFFFF00'

when i get them from the database i need to convert this string into an actual hexadecimal number, so

0xFFFF00

how can i do this in python

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604240/how-to-parse-hex-or-decimal-int-in-python

Comment: @Trevor Tipins: Well found, and the top voted answer there is a trick I didn't know about, with the 0 radix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
>>> s = '0xFFFF00'
>>> i = int(s, 16)
>>> print i
```

Answer (score 0):

`hex(int('0xFFFF00', 16))`

Comment: This gives exactly the same string, just lowercased -- what do you mean "will do it"?!

Comment: Probably not the best expression; I didn't see the answer above when I wrote it

Answer (score 0):

Also this works

```
number = int('0xFFFF00',0)
print("%x follows %x" % (number+1, number))
```

0 argument tells interpreter to follow the Python rules of numbers to decide the used format of number so this expression will work right for all numbers.