# how to convert a string into hex with the same printed string

Tags: python, string, hex

How can I convert a string `x='0x67c31080115dDfeBa0474B3893b2caB1d567438f'` into hex to be `x=0x67c31080115dDfeBa0474B3893b2caB1d567438f` ?

I want to use the same value of the hex but not in a string format

In other word, how can I treat x as a hex value not a string type ( without ' ' )

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to parse hex or decimal int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604240/how-to-parse-hex-or-decimal-int-in-python)

Comment: What exactly are you dong that requires your number to be represented internally as a hex value?  Python represents all numbers in base 10 format, but the numeric operations result in the same output regardless of if the number is octal, decimal, or hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

x='0x67c31080115dDfeBa0474B3893b2caB1d567438f'

hex_val = hex(ast.literal_eval(x))
print(hex_val)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "hex value". `0x67c31080115dDfeBa0474B3893b2caB1d567438f` belongs to type `int`. You can convert your string to `int` just with:

```
x = int(x, 16)
```

If, however, you want to print it as hex, either use:

```
print(hex(x))
```

or

```
print("{:x}".format(x))
```

(the first one adds "0x" to the beginning of the string, the other one does not).